# What is the best strategy for using color scheming tools for non-designer developers?

Tags: html, css, layout, colors

When making color choices during web design, I use free online tools such as [ColorSchemer](http://www.colorschemer.com/online.html) in which I:

- click on a color
- use the colors it suggests for me

This makes my designs look better than if I chose colors freely out of a color wheel.

But beyond this simple approach, what are are the best strategies for using these tools to make more professional color decisions?

[alt text http://i35.tinypic.com/i4ia7n.jpg](http://i35.tinypic.com/i4ia7n.jpg)

Comment: My strategy is to ask my wife.

Comment: Upvoting because it's relevant to colorblind developers as well.  ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I love using [colourlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/). Specially the palettes, since you can pick a color and get a palette with it.

Answer (score 4):

I struggle with this too.  What worked for me was the [Colour Lovers site](http://www.colourlovers.com/) and especially their [blog](http://www.colourlovers.com/blog).

This site allows users to submit and vote on color pallets and, although, they could be used for anything, many tend to be perfect for websites.

Additionally, their daily blog culls out the best and also investigates interesting color trends.  I hadn't thought I cared much about colors, but their site has started to turn me me around.

Answer (score 2):

I often use [kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/), amazing product!

Answer (score 2):

Walk in the street, go to an art gallery, look around you, take photographs.

Great colour combinations are all around.

Colourlover blog (http://www.colourlovers.com/blog) has good examples of how real things colours can make great paletes.

Yesterday's post shows a pallete constructed out of a hotdog (Chicago dog)

Answer (score 2):

This is a list of sites that I use whenever I have the 'designer's block' :)

sorry but the rules prohibited me from posting more than one 'hyperlink'...

**[ Site Design/Layout ]**

unmatchedstyle.com/

webcreme.com/

ffffound.com/

...............

**[Interfaces]**

patterntap.com/

flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/

................

I also use most of the other sites that have been mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The tools are all based on various color theories. So, it's probably best to understand that, and then the tools make more sense. There's plenty of great books on color theory.

Answer (score 0):

I find www.kuler.com to be excellent. Give it a try and let me know how you get on.